# Resealing or repolishing interior concrete floor?

Tags: concrete, flooring

I have a concrete floor in my apartment. It is somewhat shiny. When cleaning up after a pet, I used an abrasive scouring pad on it, and looks like I took off whatever layer is giving it shine:

[image: scoured concrete floor]

How do I fix this? I did some research on concrete floors, but I can’t tell whether my floor is stained, polished, or what. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe just regular old floor wax. Try cleaning the whole floor then waxing.

Comment: if there is stain that’s applied first and used to changed the overall color.  On top of that is sealer, typically clear.  Maybe on top of that is wax, so that it can be polished.  With dealers available today, the wax step isn’t common anymore.  More than likely it’s the sealer, and here is the bad news, it’s applied like paint, and just like paint it’s hard to do just one spot like this it get it to blend in, you may end up needing to reseal the entire room.

Comment: Looks like residue try rinsing with clean cloth.

Answer (score 1):

Although you might have worn through the finish if you were aggressive enough or the scouring pad was course enough, try cleaning gently (to remove any residue) and then buffing it out with a microfiber cloth and water. If that doesn't work, you'll have to check with your landlord/super/apartment manager. Scuffing of the finish shouldn't be an uncommon occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

There are industrial use floor treatments which are applied to troweled concrete.  Most are solvent based, and resist oil and water.  They have good wear properties, and with many sand and fine aggregates can be added for a slip resistant surface.

Most treatments, whether sealer type or paint type, will seek to reduce the porosity of the concrete. Wax is often used on top of sealers and paint, but may be undesirable. Once wax is applied it can be difficult to get other treatments to adhere to the concrete.

If you are able to determine that your surface has wax on it, then you can try applying some floor wax.  If not, I would avoid wax, because it could make treatment later a bigger problem.

Your landlord may know more about the floor treatment history.